# Split plane under FTDI pads USB 2.0

Tags: differential, layout, usb-c, routing, ground-loop

I want to ask you if its a critical issue
Differential signals from usb 2.0 (DP,DN _ 90ohm) routed to FTDI device FT4232HL
[image]
the pads of FTDI IC(1.58mm) goes under a split plane (the marker signals are on the TOP(Layer1) and the planes in Layer 2)

Is that something that I need to worry about it ?
if no or yes why?

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: You don't show the position of ICs or connectors in your image. It seems the signal does not cross the split, but only the pads of the FT are just on top the split?

Comment: On which plane the chip is? If it's on 3.3V plane side, how does the ground return path to the GND plane (for 5V and for USB data signald) look like?

Comment: @asdfex yes only the pads of the FT just on top of the split, please see the update

Comment: @Justme the chip on plane 3.3v the pads are split , please see the update

Comment: What's on the other layers?

Comment: Why are you splitting the ground plane between a USB socket and a USB controller?  The controller must be connected to the same ground as the USB socket, so what purpose would a split serve? If the controller shares a ground, then route over the ground.  If it doesn't, USB communications won't work, so no point in routing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a real problem here. A few points:

- impedance won't be a problem - in this area there are already the pins of the chip on top of the pads, and you don't have a well controlled impedance any more
- the discontinuity is very short compared to the wavelength of the 480 MBit/s signal
- there might be a bit of EM radiation towards the bottom side, but I wouldn't assume this to be a problem at all
- you could just extend the GND plane slightly to the left and cut a small piece from the 3.3V plane. This way your fast signal is covered.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, when there’s a split in the plane directly next to signal traces on the surface, then it has to be bridged under or right next to the signal traces. The bridge must conduct AC, so it can be metal or capacitors, but there must be a path for the return current to flow. Even in differential signaling there’s always some imbalance and a common mode signal is present. This signal will either flow on a path you provide on both  sides of the differential pair, or it will flow elsewhere - usually turning the split planes into a dipole radiator.

I’d also examine why there are split planes to bring with. Can’t you keep the GND plane continuous on layer 2, and put supplies on layer 3?